# Popup form with validation and table in jsf2 and RichFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a problem with JSF2, and RichFaces ajax, Popup I have two, one in which I display a table with data and another that appears when I want to insert a new data by clicking on a button ... but I have a problem . In fact, before the data is inserted into the table I would like to check that this is not already present, if it is I have to display an error message, otherwise close the Popup used to enter the data and display the table which is located in Popup previous year, as I proceed? you can give me an example :)

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have any unique constraints in the DB and thus it's possible to insert duplicate data while that goes against the business rules? Wouldn't you rather fix it on that side instead of in front end?

Comment: @BalusC - I think OP wants to notify the user (probably using a validator) prior to the unique constraint causing the entire transaction to fail.